# jQuery - assigning ID to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple menu, that goes like this

```
<div class=navigation">
<div class="main-menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="home">About</a></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

I need to assign an ID of "nav" to a second div (class="main-menu") and I have to do it by jQuery. Anyone can help with this?

Comment: `$('.main-menu').attr('id', 'nav')`? fetch the element with a class selector then use .attr() to assign the id

Comment: @ArunPJohny What if there's more than one element collected by `.main-menu`?

Comment: Why you want to achieve this as IDs need to be unique!

Comment: @raina77ow Then he would write like this, `$('.main-menu:has(ul.menu)')`

Comment: @Zel your html is not proper, need `"` `in class=navigation"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('.main-menu').attr('id','sm_id')
```

for targetting only second element with class `.main-menu`, you can use `eq()` selector:

```
$('.main-menu:eq(1)')
```

Comment: I'd rather use separate `eq` call, like this: `$('.main-menu').eq(1)`. In this case, it won't matter much (performance-wise) though.

Answer (score 2):

***use***

```
  $('.main-menu').attr("id","whatever")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(function(){
  $('.main-menu').attr('id','nav');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you looking for

```
$('.main-menu').attr('id', 'nav');
```

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 1):

Div class name : main-menu
Attribute name : id
Attribute Value : nav

use :

```
$('.main-menu').attr( 'id', 'nav' );
```

result :

```
<div class="main-menu" id="nav">
```